# Eclipse Deployment Assembly - Creates .war of dependency project inside main project WEB-INF/lib?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, deployment, web.xml

I have a main web project that contains all the things required to deploy and hit the page via a browser. Then I have several "functions" each as a separate project that can be included into the main project.

To take an example, I have **MainApp** and **functions.reportsApp**.

When building these with `ant` the following happens:

```
- MainApp.war
  - mainApp/jsf/Pages.faces, etc
  - reportsApp/jsf/Reports.faces, etc
  - WEB-INF/web.xml, mainapp-faces-config.xml, reportsApp-faces.config.xml, etc
  - WEB-INF/lib
     - MainApp.jar
       - META-INF/* (MainApp's)
       - my/company/MainApp/Code.class 
     - functions.reportsApp.jar
       - META-INF/* (reportsApp's)
       - my/company/reportsApp/Code.class
```

This works fine, and as I understand `.war` and `.jar` spec, is correct.

In Eclipse though, I want to have both projects open and deploy/develop to the Tomcat server setup there. I have the following:

Imported both projects, setup **MainApp** to have **ReportsApp** as a project dependency (via, MainApp-Properties, Java Build Path, Projects).

NOTE: MainApp's `web.xml` specifies:

```xml
<param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
<param-value>
/WEB-INF/reportsApp-faces-config.xml,
/WEB-INF/mainApp-faces-config.xml
</param-value>
```

reportApp's `web.xml` specifies:

```xml
<param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
<param-value>
/WEB-INF/reportsApp-faces-config.xml
</param-value>
```

I notice in MainApp-Properties-Deployment Assembly that Eclipse created:

`src:functions.reportsApp, deployPath: WEB-INF/lib`

This turns up deployed by Eclipse as `Tomcat/webapps/MainApp/WEB-INF/lib/functions.reportsApp.war`. **WAR?** This makes no sense to me and doesn't work.

To make it work, I have to:

- Add to MainApp a folder which I (via the Advanced section) Link to ReportApp's web directory.
- Add to MainApp's Deployment Assembly that linked folder and select MainApp's web folder as the 'Folder for deployment descriptor'

That gets me the `web/*` (JSF, etc.) content into `Tomcat/webapps/MainApp` and the WEB-INF content of ReportsApp merged into WEB-INF of MainApp.

I also have to make sure that MainApp's Deployment Assembly contains `functions.reportsApp.jar` to ensure that it gets deployed to tomcat under `MainApp/WEB-INF/lib`.

Surely Eclipse could have figured all this itself? That one web app depending on another web app MUST mean that the dependency would have to be deployed correctly?

Related questions:

- [Set up an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project referencing another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646684)
- [Adding a Web Project as a jar in an Eclipse Deployment Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657304)